# Spring boot data jpa OneToMany relation doesn't add foreign key

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have relation

```
public class Website {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "website", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<WebsiteCategory> website;
}

public class WebsiteCategory {
    @ManyToOne
    private Website website;
}
```

And I want to save object website with a list of websiteCategory like this

```
webSiteRepository.save(website);
```

and list with WebsiteCategories save without foreign key from website

And my question is how to save a website with a list of websitecategory with foreign key

Answer (score 0):

With this mapping a join table is created `website_website_category`. You need to add `@JoinColumn(name = "website_id")`  to your `@ManyToOne`.

Additionally consider if you have here a `@ManyToMany` relationship. A website can have many categories - hence a List. But also one category may be in many websites.